# Saving the state of the application

Tags: java, android

I have an application that does this :
When the application starts,one row with 3 `editTexts` is created by calling a method called `newproduct()`.The first of them is focused and this triggers the creation of another row of those 3 edittexts.So,when the last row is focused,another row is created dynamically.
Every columns is inside a different linear layout and gets added to a `new ArrayList<EditText>();`,one for everyone of the 3 columns.The values that get entered are then put inside a `String[]`,again,3 of them for every column.

My questions now are the following :
1.How can i save this on screen orientation changes? When i change the orientation,the values remain but only in two of the rows because those 2 rows are created at `onCreate`( newproduct method called,creates the first row, and then focused,so it creates another row).How can i tell my application to create more then 2 rows and keep the values ?

2.How can i make my application keep everything,the number of rows and their values and the whole UI layout when the user either exits the app or the app crashes.What i want here is when he enters the app again to see the state in which the app was left the last time.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

Comment: Simon,how do i retain the number of dynamically created EditTexts and then recreate them? If they were static,created thru a layout it would've been easier but what do i do in my situation ?

Comment: Is your question now "how to save arrays to a `Bundle`?

Comment: As i said,currently,with no special method like `savedInstanceState` or anything like that,my app,when the orientation is changed,will only recreate 2 of the EditText rows which are called in onCreate.My question is,if i use something like `savedInstanceState` will it do the same thing ? do i need to do something to recreate all the dynamic EditTexts ? or are they going to get recreated automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the Bundle instance for the activity. Check this link for further insight.
[Saving bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Bundle instance for the activity. You can take a look at this article on Google Developers [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)